# Variable visibility in a Groovy Script

Tags: groovy

I have created a `temp.groovy` script:

```
def loggedMessages = [];

def log(message) {
    loggedMessages << message;
}

log "Blah"

print loggedMessages.join('\n')
```

When I run it I get an exception relating to the log method:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: loggedMessages
```

Why can't the log method see the loggedMessages variable? I obviously have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on. I've tried to read the docs but I can't seem to find the relevant section.

Comment: I think the [Script Class documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_script_class) holds the answer. Near the end of the page **3.4 Variables**: *"It [the variable] will be declared in the run method that the compiler will generate and will not be visible outside of the script main body. In particular, such a variable will not be visible in other methods of the script"*. Further it mentions that removing the type definition (or `def`) will make it available to other methods.

Comment: So I need to remove the `def` when I instantiate the `loggedMessages` or annotate it with `@groovy.transform.Field`. That works! Thank you. Move this to an answer if you want the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, as an answer:

The [Script class documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_script_class) states (in the last section **3.4 Variables**) that:

*if the variable is declared as in the first example [with a type definition], it is a local variable. It will be declared in the run method that the compiler will generate and will not be visible outside of the script main body. In particular, such a variable will not be visible in other methods of the script*

And further: *if the variable is undeclared, it goes into the script binding. The binding is visible from the methods [...]*

Therefore removing the `def` from `loggedMessages` fixes the error:

```
loggedMessages = [];

def log(message) {
    loggedMessages << message;
}

log "Blah"

print loggedMessages.join('\n')
```

(Alternatively it can be annotated using `@groovy.transform.Field` as @aetheria pointed out in the comments)

Comment: Another way of solving this is to make the `log` method a closure: rewrite the line `def log(message) {` as `def log = { message ->`.